# Make SerialPort close and stop read data on window closing

Tags: c#, wpf, port

I think I have problem when I'm closing my WPF window when SerialPort is open (i guess it still receive some data). What would be best way to close it? So far i found solution, but not sure if its work.

My SerialPort settings:

```
                    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                    serialPort = new SerialPort();
                    serialPort.PortName = Application.Current.Properties["DevPort"].ToString();
                    serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                    serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                    serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                    serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    serialPort.DataReceived += serial_sp_DataReceived;
                    serialPort.Open();
```

Window.Closing method:

```
  if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            this.Closing -= Window_Closing;
            Thread CloseDown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serialPort.Dispose));
            CloseDown.Start();
        }
```

It's hard to reach that window freeze (normally it's happend 1x/10h or more). What would be best way to close/dispose serialPort before window is closed?

@EDIT:

data_received method:

```
   int count = serialPort.BytesToRead;
                byte[] ByteArray = new byte[count];
                serialPort.Read(ByteArray, 0, count);
                ByteArray = SubArray(ByteArray, 5, 5);

                string s2 = BitConverter.ToString(ByteArray);

                String[] tempAry = s2.Split('-');
                byte[] decBytes2 = new byte[tempAry.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < tempAry.Length; i++)
                    decBytes2[i] = Convert.ToByte(tempAry[i], 16);

                string host;
                int port = int.Parse(Application.Current.Properties["Port"].ToString());
                host = Application.Current.Properties["Host"].ToString();
                tekst = s2.Replace("-", "");
                string result = StartClient(host, port, tekst);

                string[] _result = result.Split('_');
                tekst = "";
                if (_result[1].ToString() == "-1")
                {
                    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowError));

                    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    thread.Start();
                    thread.Join();
                    tekst = "";
                    return;
                }
                card = _result[0];
                points = decimal.Parse(_result[1]);

                thread1 = new Thread(() => pressButton(CardButton));

                thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread1.Start();
                thread1.Join();


ShowError method just shows my custom error window. PressButton method raises    b.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

Comment: My psychic debugger says that you use Invoke() in your DataReceived event handler.  That's very apt to cause deadlock when you try to close the serial port while it is receiving data.  Use BeginInvoke() instead.

Comment: I've edited and posted my dataReceived method.

Comment: Why are you dealing with threads and graphics? It's much like shooting at the feet...consider to use async/await, if you can

Comment: The @HansPassant guess hinted me to dig, and I believe he's right. That's because the SerialPort derives from Component, which require to run in the main thread. When you call the disposal in another thread, probably causes a deadlock

Comment: Calling Thread.Join() in the DataReceived event handler is a very bad idea.  It is crucial that you don't block the event, it needs to be able to quickly complete.  Failure to do so is likely to cause deadlock, the Close() method cannot complete until the event handler stops running. Instead, use BeginInvoke() to run code on the UI thread, it can display whatever is necessary.

Comment: Ok, as you said Im trying to test now with Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke instead of new Thread

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rather generic: how to close the application when there are some threads still running? The answer is pretty obvious: ask the threads to close, and wait they really end.

However, your specific issue may be related on how the SerialPort is handled. That's because it leverages a underlying thread, and you should take care to run it as shortest as possible (that is, avoid any block).

A typical case is when you use the Read method, which blocks the flow until all the required data are read:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx

Instead, you should use another approach: first peek how many bytes are already received, then read them and none more. The total stream should be collected by your code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread(v=vs.110).aspx

Have a look at an example of mine here, old but still good:
http://cetdevelop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V2/Cet/IO/Cet.IO.Serial/SerialPortClient.cs

Answer (score 0):

You should consider disposing the serial port instance once data read has completed. Consider something like an "End of stream" mark in the data you are receiving. When you get that, dispose the serial port.